# I can't import discord in python

Tags: python, discord, bots

sorry for bad english right at the beginning :(.

I am very new to programming with Python. I just wanted to programm a bot for my Discord server. I watched a YouTube tutorial on how to set up a bot for a discord server and it just does not work how i try it ;-;.

My problem is that i can't import the discord-package. It should be done with the line

`import discord`

But it marks "discord" as an error because he can't find it. I installed it in powershell with the command

`pip install discord`

I can also find the discord folder in localappdata by

`C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: what does `python --version` say?

Comment: Was the installation successful?  What version of `pip` are you using?  Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: Take a look into using a virtual environment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by moving the "discord" folder out of the "site-packages" folder so it should be here:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with command prompt as admin again.

```
py -m pip install discord
```

If that doesn't work uninstall it and install it again

```
py -m pip uninstall discord
py -m pip install discord
```

Also if you use venv, you may need to create a file called `requirements.txt`
and type in all your third party libraries. Just type them in and press "enter". Also confirm and choose "install requirement".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :

```
pip uninstall discord
```

Then :

```
python -m pip install discord.py
```

And import again in python.

Comment: I'd rather not use the `python` command. It's just points to the latest installed version and it doesn't even work on my pc. Use something like `py -3.7 -m pip uninstall discord` and `py -3.7 -m pip install discord.py`, since this will point to the specified python version and will use the pylauncher that installs with any installation of python3.

Answer (score 0):

Install it using official discord module

```
pip install discord
```

This one is a mirror link.
Official one is this:

```
pip install discord.py
```